# DateDifference problem in v11

Tags: bugs, date-and-time, version-11

**Bug introduced in v11, fixed in v11.1**

---

I have recently upgraded to *Mathematica* 11. Here is a simplified version of code that worked in v10.2:

```
mn = DateObject[
    DateValue[DateObject[], {"Year", "Month", "Day"}],
    TimeZone -> LocalTimeZone[]];

DateDifference[mn, mn]
```

The results is an error with the message:

```
  DateDifference::date: Expression {Gregorian,Thu 15 Dec 2016EST} cannot   
  be interpreted as a date specification.
```

In v10.2, the computed and expected result is `0 days`.

I could not find any documentation that mentions a relevant change in `DateDifference` in v11.

My question is: am I missing anything?  If not, how should I go about reporting this issue?

Comment: `DateDifference[DateList@mn, DateList@mn]`.  But yeah, you shouldn't have to do that.

Comment: Anyway, the problem is the LocalTimeZone[].  Note that if you change it to 0, the code works.

Comment: Or use `TimeZone -> $TimeZone`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reported the situation as a bug to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Please edit your answer if they reply to you.